# Install Xdebug for PHP 5.6 on OSX with Homebrew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, xdebug, deprecated

The homebrew/php tap was [recently deprecated](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4721). This deprecation included versioned formulae for php installations (e.g., `php56`) as well as installation of individual extensions (e.g., `php56-xdebug`).

Installing PHP 5.6 with Homebrew now requires the command: `brew install php@5.6`.

Installing PHP 5.6 and then running `phpinfo()` indicates that Xdebug is not loaded in the list of extensions, and a debugger extension is not found. A selective copy of the output is as follows:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/php\@5.6/5.6.35/bin/php -r "phpinfo();"

PHP Version => 5.6.35

System => Darwin [my hostname] 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Mar 31 2018 20:19:57
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.35' '--localstatedir=/usr/local/var' '--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dba' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-intl' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--enable-opcache-file' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-phpdbg' '--enable-phpdbg-webhelper' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/apxs' '--with-bz2' '--with-fpm-user=_www' '--with-fpm-group=_www' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/opt/freetype' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext' '--with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp' '--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/opt/icu4c' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/opt/jpeg' '--with-kerberos' '--with-layout=GNU' '--with-ldap' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-libedit' '--with-libzip' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mcrypt=/usr/local/opt/mcrypt' '--with-ndbm' '--with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl' '--with-pdo-dblib=/usr/local/opt/freetds' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/opt/libpq' '--with-pgsql=/usr/local/opt/libpq' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/opt/libpng' '--with-pspell=/usr/local/opt/aspell' '--with-unixODBC=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' '--with-webp-dir=/usr/local/opt/webp' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xsl' '--with-zlib' '--with-curl' 'CC=clang' 'CPPFLAGS=-DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=1' 'CXX=clang++'

Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini

...
...
```

Running `brew options php` and `brew options php@5.6` yield no information on options to install additional extensions in the homebrew installation process. `brew search xdebug` yields no packages of interest.

As far as I can tell, Xdebug is not installed by default, and there is currently no mechanism to install Xdebug using homebrew with this new generic `php` formula.

Does anybody know how to go about installing Xdebug in a sensible way now that the original `homebrew/php` tap has been deprecated?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26107#issuecomment-378216899), you can install it with `pecl install xdebug`.  However, newer versions of xdebug have dropped support for PHP 5.6.  To install an older version of xdebug with support for php 5.6, use  `pecl install xdebug-2.5.5`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a crack however it complains that the `pecl/xdebug` package requires `PHP >=7.0.0`:

    cosmo:~ pcc$ pecl install xdebug
    pecl/xdebug requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.35
    No valid packages found
    install failed

I have ensured that I'm running the correct version of PHP (in the past I had two versions on, so I've run `brew unlink php55 && brew unlink php71 && brew link php@5.6` to be sure) but it complains with the same failure. I'm looking around to see if there's a way to avoid this error now.

Comment: According to the [xdebug PECL changelog](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=xdebug), the PECL package dropped support for PHP 5.6 after `version 2.5.5`. Performing an install with `pecl install xdebug-2.5.5` seems to have done the trick, and I can now debug PHP sessions with my IDE. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happy to help ! Thanks for the feedback, this might help for some future PHP 5.6 development.

Comment: Real life saver there!

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution to use the deprecated homebrew/php to install php56-extensions.

[Install PHP Extension for PHP 5.6 on OSX with deprecated homebrew/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649693/install-php-extension-for-php-5-6-on-osx-with-deprecated-homebrew-php)

I hope I've helped you

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help me out! That definitely looks like a working solution: nicely done. I'm hoping to try and come up with something that will work long term (particularly with updates) that doesn't require manual intervention beyond performing a standard brew update, but this is a great fallback position if that can't be done. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I see that homebrew/core it is updated very often. I think that in little time, also all PHP extensions will be inserted to use an standard installation process.