# Install PHP Extension for PHP 5.6 on OSX with deprecated homebrew/php

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, deprecated, php-extension

today I've update Brew and now I can't install the php56-extensions.

On my Mac is installed "php56" and today I had need to install, "php56-redis", but when I had try to install this extension, Brew returned the following error message.

```
$ brew install php56-redis

Error: No available formula with the name "php56-redis" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I see on homebrew/php page that this "tap" is deprecated and for now only PHP engine are migrated on php@5.6 but the extensions not works.

Comment: You should add your workaround as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First install exolnet/homebrew-deprecated

```
$ brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated
```

After it install deprecated package

```
$ brew install php@5.6
```

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs indeed.

Comment: Great answer... wish I found this a long time ago. Thanks!

Comment: Yes ! Thank you.

Comment: now it's not working

Answer (score 9):

I've found a solution to use old version of homebrew/php on my Mac.

**Step 1**

Go to last valid release of homebrew/php for php56

> https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/tree/966f6c318be2d80b4953cd8cdc112b9611eff8d9

and download the Zip file.

> homebrew-php-966f6c318be2d80b4953cd8cdc112b9611eff8d9.zip

**Step 2**

Go to

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/
```

and rename the Tap

> homebrew-php

in

> old-homebrew-php

**Step 3**

Unzip

> homebrew-php-966f6c318be2d80b4953cd8cdc112b9611eff8d9.zip

in

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/
```

and rename folder in

> homebrew-php

**Step 4**

Search your php extension with brew:

```
$ brew search php56-redis
==> Searching local taps...
homebrew/php/php56-redis
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
==> Searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae...
```

**Step 5**

Install pakages without updates:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install homebrew/php/<formula>
```

This will stop the homebrew update for this command. If you want to prevent auto update for your shell session, use:

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1
```

to set it permanently, add it to your ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: On Step 2 you better run `brew untap homebrew/php` to completely remove it from your system. It has been archived (it won't be updated any more) and all versions of PHP and PHP extensions were removed from it. It is useless now.

Answer (score 4):

Now at 2022, I only found https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php to be still working.

See [Error while doing `brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555525/error-while-doing-brew-tap-exolnet-homebrew-deprecated)

EDIT:

As it turned out, that you might also need legacy mysql 5.7 together with the ancient php, I ended up using [lando](https://lando.dev/) (based on docker) to get it up running. This is my .lando.yml:

```yaml
name: app
recipe: drupal6 # pulls also composer and drush as a colateral, any other php 5.6 application will work never the less
config:
  php: '5.6'
  database: mysql:5.7
  webroot: .
```

Greetings to my fellow archeologists ;)

Comment: hey guys, this needs upvotes

Comment: Hi andreas I do have an issue, I cam't install an extension after brew link, it seems not install did php restart and pc restart.