# How to install php 5.6 with homebrew if from this year it is EOL?

Tags: macos, homebrew, php-5.6, macos-high-sierra

Because php 5.6 is EOL from 01.01.2019, it was removed from homebrew.

How can I install it with homebrew even if it is not in core?

Comment: This question is duplicated : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649693/install-php-extension-for-php-5-6-on-osx-with-deprecated-homebrew-php/54466200#54466200

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install PHP Extension for PHP 5.6 on OSX with deprecated homebrew/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649693/install-php-extension-for-php-5-6-on-osx-with-deprecated-homebrew-php)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated

brew install php@5.6
```

source: https://joostvanveen.com/a-29/install-and-configure-multiple-php-versions-on-mojave-with-homebrew

Comment: The repo seems outdated. This repo https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php seems more promising.

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: https://github.com/eXolnet/homebrew-deprecated got only 21 commits.
https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php got 1970 commits atm.

Comment: It seems outdated. I tried marc.guenther's answer works.

Comment: its not working, try the other one brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@5.6

Answer (score 85):

I just used **shivammathur/homebrew-php** without any problems.

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@5.6

# point php to the 5.6 install
brew link --overwrite --force shivammathur/php/php@5.6
```

The repository is on Github:
https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php

(the **exolnet/homebrew-deprecated** mentioned in other answers doesn't seem to work anymore)

Comment: Agreed 2021 and exolnet/homebrew-deprecated does not work, but this does

Comment: Agreed January 2022, it works!

Comment: March 2022, it works! Super handy.

Comment: How to add this php location to path

Comment: June 2022 it works

Comment: July 2022, 
it's seems that the mcrypt extension is missing

Comment: September 2022, Monterey, it works

Comment: Jan 2023, Mac OS Monterey. It still works! Thank you.

Comment: this works but then... how do I run PHP? I'm sure I'll figure it out shortly.

Comment: Back then, I didn't have to do the `brew link` command you just added to my answer. No idea why it is needed for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried **exolnet/homebrew-deprecated** but it have some problem with **xdebug** & **pecl**. So I recommend you use official one.

Ref this because of long post:

- https://devhoi.com/threads/install-brew-deprecated-php-version-php-7-1-5-6-7-0-on-brew-macos.25/
- https://devhoi.com/threads/how-to-install-old-deprecated-packages-on-brew.32/

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)